# Is it correct to say "to buy something in lieu of customer"?

Tags: word-choice

A customer may buy investment funds on his/her own OR a bank may buy it FOR the customer as per his/her instructions.

In this context, is it accurate and correct to say "to buy funds in lieu of customer"?

If not, what is a better alternative?

Comment: Look up the word "proxy".

Answer (score 4):

To buy funds as [the customer's] **proxy**

> **Proxy**     *mass noun*
>
> 1. The authority to represent someone else, especially in voting: Britons
>    overseas may register to vote by proxy
>
> 1.1 [count noun] A person authorized to act on behalf of another. - *[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/proxy)*

Comment: .. and also exactly correct! :)

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, no.

[In lieu of](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in+lieu+of) has the meaning of "instead of".

You could say

> I'm buying bonds in lieu of shares, because my customer prefers investing that way.

He is choosing bonds *instead of* shares.  Notice that you're still buying FOR him, but *in lieu of* means a different thing.

A more appropriate expression would be that you're buying [on your customer's behalf](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/behalf).

Comment: exactly correct and...